# how do jquery selectors work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing the training excercise on codecademy called - Interactive website: Push menu.  There's something I don't understand about jquery selectors.  In the sample below, whey does the html element- "menu" need to have a '.' to select it in jquery and the html element 'body' does not need the '.'?

```
var main = function() {
  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 200);
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);
  });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: try reading the selectors section of the jQuery API

Comment: In most cases they 'work' precisely the same was as CSS selectors (using, where available, [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)), read: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

The period `"."` is for a CSS class.

So you probably have something like this in your HTML

```
<div class="menu">

</div>
```

Body is an html tag and therefore you can just target tags such as body, or html, or h3, etc..

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the types of identifier being used to select things.

"body" is a tag, and tags are the first class object, so no additional syntax is needed.
"menu" is a class on a tag, and classes are prefixed with a "." - hence ".menu".

Another important, and common type is an id, which is often unique on a page, and is prefixed with a #.

This syntax is shared between jquery and css.